# Rails 6 & Model Association and/or Migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-migrations

I have a question about rails 6 and model association with or without migrations.
Let me be more specific.
Let's say we want to place a foreign key inside users table which links to the id column of the courses table.
Most of the tutorials and courses i run into follow this route:

1. create a migration with add_column :users, :course_id, :integer
2. place has_one or has_many and belongs_to to the appropriate models.
   And that's it.

My thought is, how about this:

1. create a migration with add_reference :users, :course, foreign_key: true
2. place the appropriate has_one/has_many and belongs_to to the apropriate models.

or is it the same?
Doesn't the second option create indexes as well whereas the first does not?

Which is a best practice?

Comment: Having foreign keys and indexing is generally considered good practice, whether you need it or not depends on your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_reference` is meant to be a shortcut as part of the rails convention, under the hood, it will call `add_column` and other options that you specify [[you can check the code for rails-6 here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2b1b75e9ffbd6e0fe6c65fe00b746845060c90c1/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L149-L230)]

while foreign keys are not required, they are considered a best practice because they guarantee referential integrity. you can read more about it here https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys

> or is it the same? Doesn't the second option create indexes as well whereas the first does not?

having said that, your 2 migrations are not entirely the same even though they work the same (they achieve the same goal) - the second option will add an index by default unless you specify the option not to - I definitely agree with you about using `add_reference` as this is an easier and more foolproof shortcut

of course, you can also achieve that manually by using your first migration by adding an index and a foreign key as well

```rb
add_column :users, :course_id, :integer
add_index :users, :course_id # uniq or not
add_foreign_key :courses, :users
```

Comment: yes, it seems more foolproof using also the migration associations but i was a bit confused whether i should implement it since they offer the same functionality.
I used both (validation and migration) for a pesonal project im designing atm.
Plus, validations have friendlier error messages than migrations.